# How to change the Email Template of Wordpress Forgot Password?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the HTML email of Reset Password.

I tried with the filter function, but it is not working.

```
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', '_forgot_mail_content', 99, 2);
```

THANKS

Comment: Have a look at this answer to a similar question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321025/how-can-i-modify-the-default-reset-lost-password-email-text/321781#321781

Comment: Please please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include *all* of the relevant code and the details of what is going wrong so that we can help. We are not mind readers! You are not showing us the code you are using to try to do this, and saying "*it is not working*" tells us nothing.